# Conditional expectation, $X = \varphi (Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Show that if $$\forall \omega \in A \ : \ X(\omega) = \varphi(Y(\omega)),  \ \ A \in \Sigma_Y$$ (that is, the equality is true for $\omega \in A$), then $$\mathbb{E}(X|Y)(\omega) = \varphi(Y(\omega)) \text{ for almost all } \ \ \omega \in A.$$

I thought it would be a good idea to prove it for indicator functions, then for simple and measurable function.

For $Y = 1_C, \ C \in \Sigma_Y$ I get $$X(\omega) = \varphi (1_C(\omega)), \ \ \ X(\omega) = \varphi(0), \omega \in A \setminus C, \ \ \ X(\omega) = \varphi(1), \omega \in C. $$ By definition for all $B \in \Sigma_Y$: $$\int_B \mathbb{E}(X|Y)(\omega) dP = \int_B X dP = \int_{B \cap A \setminus C} \varphi(0) dP + \int_{B \cap  C} \varphi(1) dP = \varphi(0) P(B \cap A \setminus C) + \varphi(1) P(B \cap C)$$

This doesn't seem to lead me anywhere.

Could you help me prove the statement above?

Do we need to assume that $A$ is measurable?

Comment: Is the hypothesis that $X=\varphi(Y)$ *almost surely on* $\Omega$ or that $X=\varphi(Y)$ *almost surely on the event* $A$? The first option makes for a trivial question and it seems your post actually describes the second option (in which case the presently upvoted answer is off-topic) but the syntax of your post is very odd hence I wanted to be sure before posting hints.

Comment: @Did Thank you. I wrote my question down too hastily. I've corrected it now. The hypothesis is that $X=\phi(Y)$ almost surely on the event $A$.

Comment: Then, as already mentioned, the answer below does not apply. As promised, here is a hint to the actual question: The hypothesis is that $$X=\varphi(Y)\,\mathbf 1_A+X\,\mathbf 1_{\Omega\setminus A},$$ and, in this decomposition, $$\varphi(Y),\qquad\mathbf 1_A,\qquad\mathbf 1_{\Omega\setminus A},$$ are all $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. Hence, ... (This may be seen as more or less equivalent to the remark that $X\,\mathbf 1_A=\varphi(Y)\,\mathbf 1_A$ almost surely.)

Comment: @Did So eventually we get $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)= \varphi(Y) \cdot 1_A + 1_{\Omega \setminus A} \mathbb{E}(X|Y)$. Is that right?

Comment: @Did Could you also help me find a counterexample proving that the statement is false if $A$ isn't measurable?

Comment: Yes we get this identity, QED.

Comment: @Did Thanks. Could you also help me out with $A$'s measurability?

Answer (score 1):

Apply the definition of conditional expectations. The conditional expectation $\mathbf{E}[X|Y]$ is defined to be any $\sigma (Y)$-measurable function verifying for every $\psi$ (positive measurable function)

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}[\psi(Y) X ] = \mathbf{E}[\psi(Y) \mathbf{E}[X|Y]]
\end{equation}

By the definition of $X = \phi(Y)$, we have that $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable and satisfies
$$\mathbf{E}[X\psi(Y)] = \mathbf{E}[\phi(Y) \psi (Y)]$$

therefore, $\psi(Y)$ is a version of the conditional expectation $\mathbf{E}[\phi(Y)|Y]$.

**Note**. Usually, the conditional expectation is defined as I stated : for example, if $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]$ is defined to be any $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable $Z$ satisfying, for every $\mathcal{G}$-measurable positive rv $U$ : 
$$\mathbf{E}[XU] = \mathbf{E}[ZU]$$
It is known that instead of taking every positive random variable $U$, you can take every random variable having the form $\mathbf{1}_C$ where $C \in \mathcal{G}$. However, the functional definition is much more easy to handle than the other, as you just saw !

Comment: I know that if $X$ is $\Sigma_Y-$measurable then $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)=X$. But could you tell me how I can prove that $$ \begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\psi(Y) X ] = \mathbb{E}[\psi(Y) \mathbb{E}[X|Y]]
\end{equation}$$ if we define $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ as the only (up to measure 0) random variable which is measurable in $\Sigma_Y$ and $$\int_B \mathbb{E}(X|Y)(\omega) dP = \int_B X dP ?$$

Comment: If you tell that you know that if $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, then $\mathbf{E}[X|Y] = X$, then the question you asked was trivial, for $\phi(Y)$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. For the equivalence of the two definitions (the one you gave, the one I used), just use a monotone class theorem !

Comment: But can we say that $X= \varphi(Y)$ is measurable if we don't know anything about $\varphi?$ Or is it implied that $\varphi$ is measurable? I have one more question, though. Why do we need to assume that $A$ is measurable in $\sigma(Y)?$

Comment: $\phi$ has to be measurable. If not, then $\phi(Y)$ need not be $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. Now if $A$ is not measurable, expressions such as $\mathbf{E}[\mathbf{1}_A]$ or $\int_A Y(\omega)d\mathbf{P}(\omega)$ do not have any meaning !

Comment: So in order to prove the statement in my question with $X, Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}, $ and satisfying $X \cdot 1_A = \phi (Y \cdot 1_A)$ I just need to use $\mathbb{E}(X \cdot 1_A |Y \cdot 1_A )=X \cdot 1_A = \phi (Y \cdot 1_A)$, is that right? I am trying to come up with a counterexample for $A$ not being measurable.

Comment: why would it be $\phi(Y \cdot 1_A)$ and not $\phi(Y) \cdot 1_A$ ?

Comment: It's a mistake. We just multiply both sides of $X = \phi(Y)$ by the indicator function. Thanks for pointing that out.